# CSS: fixed size div, fixed vertical position and centered horizontally?

Tags: jquery, css

In CSS, is it possible to have a `<div>` that is both centered horizontally and fixed to the bottom of the browser? I'm using a set width and height for the internal div.

I've tried putting a div with `position:relative` inside a fixed outer div, and that aligns things vertically but then the outer div is not centered and I'm back to square one.

Is this even possible to do using just CSS? I'm using jQuery as well, so I would use that if it’s the only way, but I’d rather do it with CSS if it’s possible.

Thanks,
dylan

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.

HTML

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>

div#background{
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

div#content{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom:0;
    height: 700px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Setting the `div#background` width to 100% still allows the `div#content` to use `margin:auto` while still dynamically adjusting to the window width.

Comment: its answered, i just cant hit the answer button yet.

Answer (score 1):

As `div#content` is fixed width, you might be able to do away with `div#background`:

```
div#content{
    position: fixed;
    width: 800px;
    height: 700px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -350px;
}
```

Of course, if you want a 100%-width background in there, you might as well stick with your method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this :

```css
body {
   margin : 0;
   font-family : Arial;
}

.main {
    padding : 15px;
}

.footer-outer-container {
    position : fixed;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #ccc;
}

.footer-inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 20px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>
  ZE er RE GTEG ERG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  ZE er RE GTEGG EG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG g eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG  ERG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  </p>
  <p> eGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  ZE er RE GTEGG EG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG g eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG  ERG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG 
  </p>
  <p> eGE ERg erg er
  ZE er RE GTEG ERGERg erg erg er ERG  ERG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/> Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  ZE er RE GTEGG EG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG g eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG  ERG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG EG REG EG 
  </p>
  <p> eGE ERg erg er
  ZE er RE GTEG ERGERg erg erg er ERG  ERG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG ERG ERG<br/>RG ERGeGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  ZE er RE GTEGG EG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG g eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG  ERG EG ERG ERG<br/>RG ERGeGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  ZE er RE GTEGG EG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG g eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE E GTEGG EG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG g eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G EgG ERG ERG<br/>RG ERGeGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  ZE er RE GTEGG EG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG g eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG  ERG EG ERG ERG<br/>RG ERGeGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  ZE er RE GTEGG EG Eg eGERg erg erg er ERG  ERG EG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>RG ERGeGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  ZE er RE GTEGG EG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG g eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G EgG ERG ERG<br/>RG ERGeGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  ZE er RE GTEGG EG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG g eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG  ERG EG ERG ERG<br/>RG ERGeGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  ZE er RE GTEGG EG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG g eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG  ERG E eGE ERg erg erg er ERG  ERG Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG G Eg eGE ERg erg erg er ERG ERG REG EG ERG ERG<br/>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="footer-outer-container">
   <div class="footer-inner-container">
     <div class="footer">
        Center this!
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WXLsY/620/)!