# Background picture not working with fixed attachment

Tags: css, background

I am working with a project and I have come across an obstacle and I cannot seem to fix this problem. (Haha, fix)

I have a page consistent of html, php's `<?php include=""; ?>`, javascript (and jQuery) and of course, some CSS. The problem is the CSS.

The front page has [one background picture](http://www.vestervang-dejret.dk/billeder/bckground.jpg) and the subpages has [another background picture](http://www.vestervang-dejret.dk/billeder/skilt.jpg).

The subpages' picture should be positioned at "right top" and the front page picture should be positioned in a such way that the entire picture is shown.

It worked just fine when no `background-attachment:` was specified, but I have a subpage which has more text than the page can include. This, of course, makes the page scroll. I want the picture to not move (stay fixed), but when I add a "fixed" to my `background:` in the css, the picture goes nuts. This is the order, I put my stuff in `background:`

```
div#container {
    background: #ccffff url("billder/bckground.jpg") fixed no-repeat right top;
}
```

I thought that the problem would maybe be here, but I tried to seperate the tags, or whatever it's called in css, like this:

```
background-color: #ccffff;
background-image: url("billeder/bckground.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
```

Still not working (still going **wild**)

I build the page using [this method](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html) to make a div have a `min-height:` in percentage.  [This is the main page](http://www.vestervang-dejret.dk) of my project and [this is the subpage](http://vestervang-dejret.dk/omos.php) with a lot of text. As you can see, the main page goes crazy and the subpage's background picture is not properly shown, you cannot see the entire picture. The picture *is* **fixed** but not displayed the way I want it to.

I really hope you can help me, as I've put **a lot** of efford into this website.

Just to avoid any misunderstandings and annoying questions, I am not a very experienced programmer/web developer.

### EDIT

To make things clear, what I want is for the background to stay fixed (scroll along with the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `fixed` and set `min-height` (or `height` which I think looks better) to `750px` on your `<div id="container_front">...</div>`.

So it becomes this in your css:

```
div#container {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:900px;
    background-color: #ccffff;
    background-image: url("billeder/bckground.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 750px;
    min-height: 750px;
}
```

Comment: Works when fixed is not in the css-code (just like it did before), but then the picture is not fixed as I want it to be :) I want the picture to follow along with the page when you scroll down

Comment: and the reason I use min-height is, that height (in "real" browsers, which are not IE) does not allow the container to expand in size :)

Comment: I thought you wanted that - 2 sec then. You should know that the size of the background is not height enough for larger screens (such as mine)

Comment: Oh! I will fix that soon (haha, fix again) :)

Comment: Try what I have now - it looks great in Chrome (testing the others). Arrg... IE failed

Comment: hhm I will try. But actually, I thinks the site looks and feels better un-fixed.

Comment: Something just crossed my mind... Could it be that when I add "fixed", the picture "breaks loose" of the #container and applies the position "right top" to the body?

Comment: This is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262565/css-fixed-size-div-fixed-vertical-position-and-centered-horizontally